# ACF make top 10 based on field value

Tags: php, wordpress, compare, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF for a while now and I thought this would be easier but cant figure out how to do this properly...

I'm trying to create some kind of trophy cabinet. So every company has a score that is stored inside a ACF called "company_score".

For example we have companies called Microsoft, Facebook and Twitter. They all have a score:

- Facebook = 200000
- Microsoft = 900000
- Twitter = 100000

So the top 3 wil be like

- 1) Microsoft
- 2) Facebook
- 3) Twitter

I know how to display the value of an ACF but how can I compare all the scores that are stored and when a company has the best score it will display a gold medal. When a company has the second best score it will display a silver medal and so on.

I all had it figured it out in my head but a bit stuck here how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several approaches to handle this. The first one, which comes in my mind is very simple.

**Try these steps:**

1. Pull all fields
2. Store in an array
3. Sort the array in ascending order
4. Display the results.

I hope, you've some understanding of the code but here are the coded guidelines...

```
<?php 

   $fields = get_fields();
   $company_details = array();

   if( $fields ): 

      foreach( $fields as $name => $value ):

        $company_details[ $name ] = $value;


      endforeach;

   endif;

   //to sort by company score
   arsort( $company_details );

   //loop through the array and display results, like
   foreach( $company_details as $name => $value):

      echo "Company name is: " .$name. ". Company Score: " . $value;

   endforeach;
```

**PS:** The code is not tested because the purpose was to share logic with you. So, ignore if there's any error.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out. Put everything in an array and did like you suggested! Thanks a lot!